# PayPal Express Parallel Payment - No Cart shown

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I have a little problem with my integration. I use PayPal Express with Parallel Payment. If I use the following code (The $params are via curl transmitted - SetExpressCheckout):

```
$params = array(
'RETURNURL' => $rootURL . "return.php",
'CANCELURL' => $rootURL . "cancel.php",
'NOSHIPPING' => '1',
'BRANDNAME' => 'My Shop',   
'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT' => '1.37',
'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE' => 'EUR',
'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT' => '1.37',
'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID' => 'email_1@domain.com',
'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTREQUESTID' => 'GHTFVGFUOLG',
'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION' => 'Sale',
'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0' => 'Test Item 1',
'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0' => '1',
'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0' => '1.37'
);
```

it works fine - I see a cart list like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXtna.jpg

But if I'm using this code including a second receiver:

```
$params = array(
'RETURNURL' => $rootURL . "return.php",
'CANCELURL' => $rootURL . "cancel.php",
'NOSHIPPING' => '1',
'BRANDNAME' => 'My Shop',   
'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT' => '1.00',
'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE' => 'EUR',
'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT' => '1.00',
'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID' => 'email_1@domain.com',
'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTREQUESTID' => 'GHTFVGFUOLG',
'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION' => 'Sale',
'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0' => 'Test Item 1',
'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0' => '1',
'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0' => '1.00',
'PAYMENTREQUEST_1_AMT' => '3.00',
'PAYMENTREQUEST_1_CURRENCYCODE' => 'EUR',
'PAYMENTREQUEST_1_ITEMAMT' => '3.00',
'PAYMENTREQUEST_1_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID' => 'email_2@domain.com',
'PAYMENTREQUEST_1_PAYMENTREQUESTID' => 'HFTZIGDTUGFD',
'PAYMENTREQUEST_1_PAYMENTACTION' => 'Sale',
'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_1_NAME0' => 'Test Item 2',
'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_1_QTY0' => '1',
'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_1_AMT0' => '3.00'
);
```

No cart is shown - only the amount. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/ga9ys.jpg

What's wrong here?

Comment: Is this and old application? Looks like PayPal deprecated this... `https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-parallelPayments/#` what do you think?

Comment: Yes it's deprecated. I could not find any newer method to implement parallel payment. But I think that's not the fault.